# jsp toggle button, save the corresponding value to DB

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

I am currently working on a smart farm project with my team members using jsp.

I'm trying to create a toggle button on the main page so that a specific value of on:255 / off:0 is stored in the DB. I first created a toggle button and tried to solve it using chatGPT, but I could not solve it. Please help...

The current environment DB consists of power table [num(AI), waterPumpPower(int), ledPower(int), fanPower(int).

main.jsp

```
  <div class="form-check form-switch">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="물펌프" onchange="updateSensorStatus('물펌프');" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="물펌프">물펌프</label>

  </div>
```

The water pump power sensor button is configured like this, and the other two buttons are configured in the same way.

```
    <script>
        function updateSensorStatus(sensorId) {
            // 올바른 sensorId인지 체크
            const validSensors = ['물펌프', '조도', '쿨링'];
            if (!sensorId || !validSensors.includes(sensorId)) {
                console.error('Invalid sensorId:', sensorId);
                return;
            }
    
            let isChecked = document.getElementById(sensorId).checked;
            let status = isChecked ? "on" : "off";
    
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'updateSensor.jsp', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        // 성공적으로 요청이 완료된 경우
                        alert('센서 상태가 업데이트되었습니다.');
                    } else {
                        // 요청이 실패한 경우
                        alert('센서 상태 업데이트에 실패하였습니다.');
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.send('sensorId=' + sensorId + '&status=' + status);
        }
    </script>
```

And the Main.jsp JavaScript is also structured like this.

---

updateSensor.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import="power.PowerDAO" %>


<%
  // 클라이언트로부터 받은 데이터 추출
  String sensorId = request.getParameter("sensorId");
  String status = request.getParameter("status");

  if (sensorId == null) {
    out.print("sensorId is null"); // 디버깅용 메시지
    return;
  }


  // 데이터베이스 연동 객체 생성
  PowerDAO dao = new PowerDAO();

  switch (sensorId) {
    case "물펌프":
      dao.updateWaterPumpStatus(status); // 메소드 이름 수정
      break;
    case "조도":
      dao.updateLightStatus(status); // 메소드 이름 수정
      break;
    case "쿨링":
      dao.updateFanStatus(status); // 메소드 이름 수정
      break;
    default:
      out.print("Invalid sensorId");
      return;
  }

  out.print("Update Successful");
  System.out.println("sensorId: " + sensorId);
  System.out.println("status: " + status);

   // 아래 코드는 중복이므로 제거되었습니다.
   dao.updateWaterPumpStatus(status);
   System.out.println("Water Pump status updated.");


%>


--------------
```

Power.java

```
package power;

public class Power {

    private int num;
    private int ledPower;
    private int waterPumpPower;
    private int fanPower;

    public Power(int num, int ledPower, int waterPumpPower, int fanPower) {
        this.num = num;
        this.ledPower = ledPower;
        this.waterPumpPower = waterPumpPower;
        this.fanPower = fanPower;

    }


    public int getNum() {

        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {

        this.num = num;
    }

    public int getLedPower() {

        return ledPower;
    }

    public void setLedPower(int ledPower) {

        this.ledPower = ledPower;
    }

    public int getWaterPumpPower() {

        return waterPumpPower;
    }

    public void setWaterPumpPower(int waterPumpPower) {

        this.waterPumpPower = waterPumpPower;
    }

    public int getFanPower() {
        return fanPower;
    }

    public void setFanPower(int fanPower) {
        this.fanPower = fanPower;
    }

}
```

---

PowerDAO.java

```
package power;

import java.sql.*;

public class PowerDAO {
    private Connection conn;
    private PreparedStatement pstmt;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public PowerDAO() {
        try {
            String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://------";
            String dbID = "----";
            String dbPassword = "----";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbID, dbPassword);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateWaterPumpStatus(String status) {
        updateSensorStatus("waterPumpPower", status);
    }

    public void updateLightStatus(String status) {
        updateSensorStatus("ledPower", status);
    }

    public void updateFanStatus(String status) {
        updateSensorStatus("fanPower", status);
    }

    private void updateSensorStatus(String column, String status) {
        try {
            int value = "on".equalsIgnoreCase(status) ? 255 : 0;

            // num이 가장 높은 레코드를 찾습니다.
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT MAX(num) as maxNum FROM power");
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                int maxNum = rs.getInt("maxNum");

                // 해당 num 값의 레코드의 센서 컬럼 값을 업데이트합니다.
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE power SET " + column + " = ? WHERE num = ?");
                pstmt.setInt(1, value);
                pstmt.setInt(2, maxNum);
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
            } // 만약 레코드가 없다면 아무 작업도 하지 않습니다.

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeResources();
        }
    }

    private void closeResources() {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (pstmt != null) {
                pstmt.close();
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate your help in resolving the issue.

If you run the code above, it will not be saved to the DB. / Also, when you run the updateSensor.jsp page, the message “sensornull” appears.

If there is another way to solve it, please let me know.

Comment: Does it return a response from xhr?